# problem calling summernote callbacks in angular10

Tags: angular, angular10, summernote

I am developing a form in **angular 10** and implement **summernote**. one of the things I have to implement is that when inserting an image in the form it is saved in the back-end but it does not access the function. They told me that a correct way would be to use **ngZone** but never use it. Problems that come up with the **onImageUpload** and **onImageLinkInsert** callbacks do not work, *$ (el) .summernote (* gives me the error Property *'summernote' does not exist on type 'JQuery'*

This is the code. component.ts

```
  config = {
    tabsize: 2,
    height: '300px',
    toolbar: [
      ['misc', ['undo', 'redo']],
      ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
      ['para', ['style']],
      ['table', ['table']],
      ['insert', ['picture', 'link', 'hr']],
    ],
    disableDragAndDrop: true,
    callbacks: {
      onImageUpload: function (files, editor, welEditable) {
        console.log('onImageUpload');
        for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          this.sendFile(files[i], this);
        }
      },
      onImageLinkInsert: function (url) {
        // // url is the image url from the dialog
        let img = $('<img>').attr({ src: url });
        this.summernote.summernote('insertNode', img[0]);
        console.log('onImageLinkInsert');
      },

      onPaste: function (e) {
        //Para evitar el paste con formato
        var bufferText = (
          (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || ClipboardEvent.call
        ) /*|| window.clipboardData*/
          .getData('Text');
        e.preventDefault();
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText);
        console.log('onPaste');
      },
    },
  };
```

```
 sendFile(file, el) {
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file);
    console.log(el);
    //this.ImageService.setImagenPDF()
        $.ajax({
            data: form_data,
            type: "POST",
            url: '/img/pdf',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer ****"
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {

                var img = $('<img />').attr({ src: response.url })
                img.attr('data-fileId', response.id);
                $(el).summernote('insertNode', $img[0]);
            }
        });
  }
```

component.ts

```
<textArea formControlName="html" #refsummernote id="summernote" [ngxSummernote]="config"></textArea>
```

the summernote library I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-summernote